# what does state, session_state, and code url paremeters from a keycloak redirect represent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

What does the state, session_state and code url parameters represent in the url string after getting a redirect after logging in via keycloak?

I do keycloak.init to require a login and get redirected to the ChatPage portion of my react app:

```
this.state.appKeycloak.init({
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/ChatPage'
})
```

After logging in to my local react app on http://localhost:3000 I see this in the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/ChatPage#state=7....1&session_state=e...70&code=c...f6
```

What does the **state**, **session_state**, and **code** fields represent?  Do any of them have the token I can decode to get the users login information?

Answer (score 1):

No, none of them do. Those are all parameters from various standards.

`code` is used for authorization code flow to exchange for the tokens at the token endpoint. You can get the `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `id_token` at the token endpoint by using the `code`.

`state` is used to prevent CSRF attacks either by attackers initiating requests to the authorization endpoint or forging responses to the application redirect endpoint.

`session_state` is part of the OpenID Connect Session Management specification where you use an iframe to check if the SSO user has logged out for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Likely what you really want to know is the following

```js
const authenticated = await keycloak.init({
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/ChatPage'
});
if(authenticated) {
    console.log(keycloak.token);
    console.log(keycloak.tokenParsed);
    console.log(keycloak.idToken);
    console.log(keycloak.idTokenParsed);
    console.log(keycloak.refreshToken);
    console.log(keycloak.refreshTokenParsed);
    console.log(keycloak.sessionId);
    console.log(keycloak.subject);
    console.log(keycloak.realmAccess);
    console.log(keycloak.resourceAccess);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).